# issue with the image alignment?

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I am trying to put the image at the top of of my device and these are the constrains that i am applying[image]

The result that i am getting by applying this result is

[image]

so there is some black space left at the top, i want that my image should stick to the top, i want to conserve the aspect ratio of the image and can't clip it so i can't use aspect fill. Can someone help me out with this

Comment: it seems your constraints are being laid out according to the top layout guides, which account for a status bar and navigation controller. Can you manually position that pink view to where you want it and then select "Update Constraints"

Comment: @LouisTur Thanks for the reply. When i am manually positioning the view and updating the constrain, pink view is going back to its old position. When i am selecting aspect fill the the pink view is filling the top but its cropping the text

Comment: ooh, hang on.. so the pink view is actually an image inside an imageview? so then keep the aspect fit, but change the size of the actual imageview